# Poliastro plot not showing up in Jupyter

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook, astronomy

Just started learning poliastro and it's already not working.
Tried plotting their example code here https://github.com/poliastro/poliastro:

```
%matplotlib inline

from poliastro.examples import molniya

molniya.plot()
```

but nothing came out :( Doesn't work with `plt.show()` either

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: @HS-nebula, no error, just no output at all